# Несовместимость старой и новой версий асинхронного клиент- серверного приложения C#

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер, мобильные-приложения

Есть приложение, архитектура клиент- сервер, идея такая что клиент типа 1 кидает пакет серверу- сервер обрабатывает каким то образом - кидает измененный пакет клиенту типа 2. 
В новой версии в одном из пакетов должно поменяться количество параметров, вместо  6 стало 7. И у клиента типа 1, и клиента типа 2, и сервера. Но если на сервере я еще могу сделать какую то проверку на количество параметров на принятие старых и новых пакетов, то какое количество параметров в пакете отправлять клиенту типа 2 (для старой или для новой версии), ума не приложу.
И на сервере. и на клиенте типа 2 есть валидация входящих пакетов. 
Да, клиенты типа1 и типа 2 - мобильные приложения, и если для андроида обновление становится доступным достаточно быстро, то для айоса нужно 2 недели ждать.
Что посоветуете? Я еще с таким не сталкивалась, опыт не сильно большой, не знаю что делать...

Comment: То есть, проблема в том, что клиенту типа 2 нужно отправлять ответ, при этом не известно, какой он версии?

Comment: Да, совершенно верно.

Comment: Может можно как то версию клиента узнать, гуглю, пока ничего не нашла.

Comment: Последствие изначально неверного дизайна. Я бы в запросах первым параметром указывал версию или количество аргументов, чтобы принимающий мог оперировать с предыдущими и новыми версиями. Сетью сам не занимаюсь, могу только посоветовать только в ближайшей новой версии перейти на более гибкую архитектуру, вроде описанной выше. Ну или отправлять два ответа, если один из них сей равно будет проигнорирован :)

Comment: Если категорически нужно поддерживать работу обеих версий - оставляйте поддержку на сервере. Хотя бы до след обновления.

Comment: Да, архитектура оставляет желать лучшего. Я на поддержке проекта работаю. Насчет отправки 2 пакетов - идея, надо попробовать.

Comment: @Helen если это сработает, и других вариантов не найдётся, могу написать ответ.

Comment: @AivanF., сработало! А еще есть какое то решение?

Comment: Если сработало - то отметьте ответ такой зеленой галочкой.

Comment: Для получения "еще каких-то решений" укажите хотя бы, какая технология используется для клиент-серверного взаимодействия.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возникшие у Вас проблемы — последствие изначально неверной архитектуры. Она должна быть гибкой, иметь возможность как-то работать с версиями новее или старее. И что-нибудь такое Вам нужно как можно скорее реализовать в проекте.

Я бы сделал так: в запросах первым параметром указывать версию и/или количество аргументов, чтобы принимающий мог оперировать урезать лишний аргументы или вставлять значения по умолчанию.

А на данный момент только "костыли" помогут: раз сообщение с не совпадающим количеством параметров игнорируется, то можно просто посылать два сообщения для обоих версий. Возможно, найдётся ещё какое-нибудь временное решение, но для этого нужно учитывать различные технические нюансы.

Answer (score 1):

Возможен еще и такой вариант - 2 сервера на разных портах, старая и новая версия. Старый клиент работает как раньше, новый клиент цепляется к новому серверу.

Если архитектура позволяет, можно сделать один сервер, который работает на разных протоколах, каждый протокол на своем порту.

Если вы используете такие технологии как WCF, то там есть свои [рекомендации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731060(v=vs.110).aspx) по версионированию протокола.

Comment: "Старый клиент работает как раньше, новый клиент цепляется к новому серверу" - так не получится, когда клиенты 1 и 2 разных версий. На сервере  много данных хранится в объектах, пока идет сессия, который гоняет их туда-сюда.

Comment: @Helen сессионные объекты - не проблема, ведь у клиента будет сессия всего на одном сервере, а не на двух сразу.

Comment: @Helen вот если клиенты не являются независимыми и есть общесерверное состояние - то да, два сервера уже не запустить.

Comment: да, клиенты зависимы, и есть общесерверное состояние.

Comment: @Helen ну значит, можно 1 сервер с двумя протоколами поднять. Или воспользоваться другим решением.

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант.

Переносим сервер на новый порт, где он будет обслуживать новых клиентов. На старом порту поднимаем прокси, который будет преобразовывать протокол: добавлять параметр в одну сторону и удалять его в другую.